# Como leer un archivo XML y validar con los datos de una tabla

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sql-server, xml

Estoy en la creación de una funcionalidad que permita cargar archivos XML pero antes de cargarlos requiero verificar su contenido, no se si sea la manera correcta pero estaba pensando en algo como primero leer el XML para revisar su contenido y luego validarlo con los datos que tengo almacenados en una tabla de base de datos.

De momento lo que he desarrollado hasta ahora es la carga del archivo XML haciendo uso de AJAX y PHP de la siguiente manera.

Este es parte del formulario con el cual cargo mis archivos XML

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
              </div>
                    </div>
                    

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Documentos</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

La siguiente es la función JQuery con la cual cargo el documento y valido su formato

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#upload").on("click", function(){
        const ArchivoXml = $("#XmlToUpload").prop('files')[0];          

        //Validación para comprobar que sea el formato correcto
        if (ArchivoXml.type !== 'text/xml') {
            $('#XmlToUpload').val('');
            //$('#pdfToUpload').val('');
            alert('Por favor seleccione los archivos con el formato correcto');
            return;
          }

        const datosForm = new FormData;

        datosForm.append("XmlToUpload", ArchivoXml);
       
        const filePath="server.php"
        //console.log(ArchivoXml);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: datosForm,
            url:filePath
        }).done(function(data){
            alert(data)
        }).fail(function(){
            alert('El archivo no se pudo cargar')
        });       
    });   
});
```

El siguiente es el código PHP con el cual indico la ruta donde se almacenara

**server.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"])){
        $archivo = $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["name"];
        $ruta ="XML/";

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$archivo)){
            echo "Subido exitosamente";
        }else{
            echo "Error al subir";
        }          
    }else {
        echo "No se selecciono un archivo";
    }
?>
```

Como lo comente al comienzo de la pregunta requiero validar el contenido del XML y validarlo con la información que se encuentra en una tabla de base de datos.

La estructura del archivo XML va a contener la siguiente información:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante Version="3.3" Total="45264.13">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="ABC123456AB1" Nombre="JOHN DOE"/>
     <cfdi:Conceptos>
         <cfdi:Concepto ValorUnitario="93.80">
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
     <cfdi:Complemento>
        <tfd:Digital Version="1.1" />
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Aquí los datos que me interesa validar son `Total="45264.13"` y `Rfc="ABC123456AB1"`

Adicional a esto me puse en la tarea de crear un Procedimiento Almacenado en **SQLServer** para obtener la información desde la Base de datos y así comparar con los datos del XML y el valor de los campos de la tabla en Base de datos.

```
USE [dbtest]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sptest]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptest]
    
AS
BEGIN
    
    Select VTB.RFC as 'RFC',
           LRC.QTY as 'Recibido',  
           PL.PRICE as 'Precio',
           (PL.PRICE *LRC.QTY) * 1.16 as 'Total'
    from PACKING RC  
        inner join VTABLE VTB on VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
        inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID)
        inner join PURCH PL on (PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM and PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH)      
END
```

Espero que alguien me pueda orientar un poco con esta funcionalidad que estoy creando.

**Actualización:**

Con el objetivo de darle una validación mucho mas rápida a que los datos sean iguales a los del contenido del XML, ahora he decido obtenerlos en el front, es decir, mostrarlos en la misma vista donde cargo el XML de la siguiente manera:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lblNombreVisita" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">RFC:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRfc" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>
           <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lblNombreVisita" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Total:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTotal" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> Archivo XML:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" required>
                  </div>
                        </div>
                        

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success">Subir Documentos</button>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Igualmente si alguien encuentra como validarlos a que sean igual a los valores que se encuentran en la base de datos también es valido o si se pueden validar directamente con los valores que estoy obteniendo en los campos de texto que acabo de agregar también es valido.

**Actualización 2:**

Como se me indica en alguno de los comentarios a la pregunta he preparado la sentencia en PHP, donde paso como parámetros el RFC y Total.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"])){
        $archivo = $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["name"];
        $ruta ="XML/";
        
        $serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
        
        if ($conn === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        
        $sql = "Select VTB.RFC as 'RFC',
            LRC.QTY as 'QTY',  
            PL.PRICE as 'Price',
            (PL.PRICE *LRC.QTY) * 1.16 as 'Total'
        from PACKING RC  
            inner join VTABLE VTB on VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
            inner join TRANS LRC on (LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID)
            inner join PURCH PL on (PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM and PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH)   
        where VTB.RFC = ? AND ((PL.PRICE * LRC.QTY) * 1.16) = ?";
        
        $params = array($rfc, $total);
        $options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params, $options);
        $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
        
        if ($row_count === false) {
        echo "Error";
        }else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$ruta.$archivo)){
            echo "Subido exitosamente";
        }else{
            echo "Error al subir";
            }
        }                 
    }else {
        echo "No se selecciono un archivo";
    }
?>
```

**Actualización 3:**

En base a una de las respuestas que me aportan he obtenido el siguiente codigo en mi desarrollo:

```
<?php
    // Obtén número de factura o cadena vacía
$factura = (isset($_POST['factura'])) ? trim($_POST['factura']) : '';
  print_r($factura);
  echo "Probando";

  // Define el arreglo que vas a devolver
  $res = [
      'factura' => ($factura != ''),
      'xml' => (isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]) && $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]['error'] == 0),
      'pdf' => (isset($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]) && $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]['error'] == 0)
  ];


  // Solo si hay número de factura
  if($res['factura']) {

    $errores = array( UPLOAD_ERR_OK => 'Carga exitosa'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (PHP)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (HTML)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => 'Carga incompleta'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => 'No se seleccionó archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Falta carpeta temporal'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'No se guardó el archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => 'Una extensión bloqueó la carga'
                    );

      // Solo si se subió archivo XML y no tuvo error
      if($res['xml']) {
          $archivo = $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]["name"];
      $ruta ="XML/";


      if( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
        // error_log($errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']]);
        die( $errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']] );
    }

      $xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true );
      $total = (float)$xml['Total'];
      $rfc = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Emisor[0]->attributes()['Rfc'];

      

      include './db/conectar.php';
      if( $conn === false ){
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }

      $sql = "{call SPValidarXML(?,?)}";

      $params = array($rfc, $total);
      $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params );

      if( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) ){
        $destino = 'XML/'.$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $destino))
        
        echo 'Subido exitosamente';

        else {
          echo 'Error al mover a directorio destino';
        }           
    } else {
        echo 'RFC/Total no identificado';
    }
  }

      // Solo si se subió archivo PDF y no tuvo error
      if($res['pdf']) {
          $archivo = $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["name"];
          $ruta ="PDF/";

          if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $ruta . $archivo)) {
              // Hubo error, poner propiedad en falso
              $res['pdf'] = false;
          }          
      }
      // ¿Se subieron los dos archivos?
      if($res['xml'] && $res['pdf']) {
          // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para actualizar estado de factura
          // Ya tienes el número en la variable $factura
          $query = array();
          include './db/conectar.php';
          $sql = "{call SPCambioEstatus(?)}";

          $factura = (isset($_POST['factura'])) ? trim($_POST['factura']) : '';
         
          $params = array($factura);
          print_r($params);

          $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
          if ( $stmt === false) {
              die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
          }

          session_start();


          sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);     
          sqlsrv_close($conn);
      }
  }
  // Devuelves el arreglo
  echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

**NOTA:**

Es importante resaltar aquí que junto a la carga del archivo XML también cargo un archivo PDF como ven en el código después de la validación del archivo XML realizo la carga del PDF y una vez ambos archivos estén cargados se ejecutara un procedimiento almacenado que cambiara de Estatus pero es algo que no tiene relevancia en cuanto a lo que estoy solicitando en la pregunta inicial, solo lo agrego para mantenerlos al tanto de lo que tengo en mi código.

Adicionalmente en el código que me han aportado he realizado un cambio en la forma de obtener la consulta, en mi caso he creado un procedimiento almacenado llamado `SPValidarXML` al cual le envió dos parámetros `RFC` y `Total`, toda la cadena de conexión se encuentra en el archivo `conectar.php`

**Actualización 4:**

He logrado concluir la funcionalidad de la lectura del XML y la validación pero he estado presentando un problema con una validación extra que tengo en mi código actual, como lo comente en mi ultima actualización cuento con una validación que cambiara de estatus apenas se carguen los dos archivos PDF y XML, cuando cargo el archivo XML y sus datos no son correctos se ejecuta la validación que tengo de cambio de estatus, quiero evitar que si los datos no son correctos pues que no se ejecuta esta validación de cambio de estatus, el codigo actual que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    // Obtén número de factura o cadena vacía
$factura = (isset($_POST['factura'])) ? trim($_POST['factura']) : '';

  // Define el arreglo que vas a devolver
  $res = [
      'factura' => ($factura != ''),
      'xml' => (isset($_FILES["XmlToUpload"]) && $_FILES["XmlToUpload"]['error'] == 0),
      'pdf' => (isset($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]) && $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]['error'] == 0)
  ];
  // Solo si hay número de factura
  if($res['factura']) {

    $errores = array( UPLOAD_ERR_OK => 'Carga exitosa'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (PHP)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (HTML)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => 'Carga incompleta'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => 'No se seleccionó archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Falta carpeta temporal'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'No se guardó el archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => 'Una extensión bloqueó la carga'
                    );

      // Solo si se subió archivo XML y no tuvo error
      if($res['xml']) {
      if( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
        // error_log($errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']]);
        die( $errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']] );
    }
      
      $xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true );
      $factura = (isset($_POST['factura'])) ? trim($_POST['factura']) : '';
      $total = (float)$xml['Total'];
      $rfc = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Emisor[0]->attributes()['Rfc'];

      $serverName = "serverName";
      $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database", "UID"=>"UID", "PWD"=>"PWD");            
      $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

      if( $conn === false ){
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
      }

      $sql = "SELECT RC.ID as 'factura'
                    VTB.RFC as 'RFC',
                   LRC.QTY as 'QTY',  
                   PL.PRICE as 'Price',
                   (PL.PRICE *LRC.QTY) * 1.16 as 'Total'
              FROM PACKING RC  
                INNER JOIN VTABLE VTB 
                  ON VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
                INNER JOIN TRANS LRC 
                  ON LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID
                INNER JOIN PURCH PL 
                  ON    PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM 
                    AND PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH
              WHERE VTB.RFC = ? 
                AND ((PL.PRICE * LRC.QTY) * 1.16) = ?
                AND RC.FACTURA = ?
           ";

      $params = array($rfc, $total, $factura,);
      $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params );

      if( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) ){
        $destino = 'XML/'.$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
        if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $destino))
        
        echo 'Subido exitosamente';

        else {
          echo 'Error al mover a directorio destino';
        }           
    } else {
        echo 'RFC/Total no identificado';
    }    
      
  }

      // Solo si se subió archivo PDF y no tuvo error
      if($res['pdf']) {
          $archivo = $_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["name"];
          $ruta ="PDF/";

          if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdfToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $ruta . $archivo)) {
              // Hubo error, poner propiedad en falso
              $res['pdf'] = false;
          }          
      }

      // ¿Se subieron los dos archivos?
      if($res['xml'] && $res['pdf']) {
          // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para actualizar estado de factura
          // Ya tienes el número en la variable $factura
          $query = array();
          include './db/conectar.php';
          $sql = "{call SPEstatus(?)}";

          $factura = (isset($_POST['factura'])) ? trim($_POST['factura']) : '';
         
          $params = array($factura);
         // print_r($params);

          $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
          if ( $stmt === false) {
              die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
          }

          session_start();


          sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);     
          sqlsrv_close($conn);
      }

  }
  // Devuelves el arreglo
  echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

No se si se deba cambiar algo en el orden en como estoy ejecutando mis validaciones pero como les digo lo que quiero es que cuando me genere el error de `RFC/Total no identificado` no se ejecute la ultima validación que tengo de cambio de estados de factura.

Comment: Validar RFC y total contra la base de datos, pero ¿qué es válido? ¿Que sean iguales, distintos, que exista (o no) en la base de datos?

Comment: @Sal Hola, que sean iguales a los valores que se encuentran en base de datos

Comment: Entonces mejor convierte el procedimiento almacenado en una sentencia preparada en PHP, pasando como parámetros el RFC y el monto.

Comment: @Sal Puedes aportarme por favor un ejemplo como respuesta para darle validez

Comment: @Sal Acabo de agregar la sentencia preparada en PHP tal como lo indicaste, ves posible que puedas agregar la validación ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Valida lo errores de carga del archivo.
2. Extrae los valores del CFDI.
3. Valida con una sentencia preparada. El primer fetch exitoso significa que se identificó el CFDI.

```
<?php
    $errores = array( UPLOAD_ERR_OK => 'Carga exitosa'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (PHP)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (HTML)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => 'Carga incompleta'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => 'No se seleccionó archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Falta carpeta temporal'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'No se guardó el archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => 'Una extensión bloqueó la carga'
                    );
    // Verificar la transmisión del archivo
    if( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
        // error_log($errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']]);
        die( $errores[$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['error']] );
    }

    
    $xml = new SimpleXMlElement( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], 0, true );
    $total = (float)$xml['Total'];
    $rfc = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Emisor[0]->attributes()['Rfc'];
    
    
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( 'serverName\\sqlexpress'
                          , array( 'Database' => 'dbName'
                                 , 'UID' => 'userName'
                                 , 'PWD' => 'password'
                                 )
                          );
    if( $conn === false )
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        
    $sql = "SELECT VTB.RFC as 'RFC',
                   LRC.QTY as 'QTY',  
                   PL.PRICE as 'Price',
                   (PL.PRICE *LRC.QTY) * 1.16 as 'Total'
              FROM PACKING RC  
                INNER JOIN VTABLE VTB 
                  ON VTB.COLUMN = RC.INVOICE
                INNER JOIN TRANS LRC 
                  ON LRC.PACKING = RC.RECID
                INNER JOIN PURCH PL 
                  ON    PL.NUMBER =LRC.NUM 
                    AND PL.PURCH =RC.PURCH
              WHERE VTB.RFC = ? 
                AND ((PL.PRICE * LRC.QTY) * 1.16) = ?
           ";
    $params = array( $rfc, $total );
    $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params );
    if( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) ){
        $destino = 'XML/'.$_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
        if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name']
                              , $destino
                              )
          )
            echo 'Subido exitosamente';
        else
            echo 'Error al mover a directorio destino';
    } else {
        echo 'RFC/monto no identificado';
    }
```

Comment: He agregado una actualización adaptada a mi código pero he tenido error al validar el XML después de la carga del archivo me arroja como mensaje  `RFC/monto no identificado`  y cuando reviso la ubicación del archivo en donde lo estoy almacenando allí me aparece el archivo XML, crees que hay algo que estoy haciendo mal o deba modificar ?

Comment: ¿Qué regresa el procedimiento? ¿Devuelve algo `sqlsrv_errors()`?. Cuando hay problemas usando `call` la alternativa es usar `EXEC`.

Comment: Como puedo comprobar lo que esta regresando el procedimiento ? Quieres que agregue el procedimiento ? Como compruebo si `sqlsrv_errors()`  devuelve algo ?

Comment: Hay alguna novedad con respecto al error que estoy obteniendo ? No creo que haga falta mucho para darle validez a tu respuesta

Comment: Revisando a detalle el codigo que agregas a tu respuesta veo que la sentencia  `$total = (float)$xml['Total'];` se lee diferente a como lo hace la sentencia `$rfc = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Emisor[0]->attributes()['Rfc'];` hay algo mas que se deba agregar ?

Comment: Te recomiendo que pruebes el código como lo puse. En este punto no es conveniente agregar un grado mas de complejidad con el procedimiento almacenado si aún no los dominas, debuguearlo merece una pregunta y respuesta aparte. Haz en php `echo sqlsrv_errors();` y coméntanos.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha funcionado parcialmente bien hasta ahora, pero he tenido algunos detalles con el orden de las validaciones o la ubicación correcta del código, cuando ocurre un error al leer el archivo o sus datos no son correctos se ejecuta la ultima validación donde tengo el procedimiento almacenado llamado `SPEstatus`, hay algo que deba cambiar en el orden del código o la ubicación ?

Comment: Aun no logro completar la funcionalidad de leer y validar el XML, es posible que el código que agregase como respuesta se pueda adaptar al código que tengo en mi pregunta inicial ?

Comment: Cambia `echo 'RFC/monto no identificado';` por `die('RFC/monto no identificado');`